# Select menu on object of object

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a object who have a object with colors key.

I want display in select menu , all the index of the 'version' object

select [ 0,1,2,3,....]

this is my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianczech/2wfapuv4/21/

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="app">
<v-app >
<h1>Selection</h1>
<v-select
  v-for="c in car "
  :items="c.version"
>
</v-select>
</v-app>
</div>
```

```
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {

  // #1 method to add line
  // # method to console an object like { time:intensity, time:intensity, time:intensity,... } so for example { 10:50, 20:80, 50:40, ....}

  },
  data() {
    return {
        car: [
                    {
                        name: 'McQueen',
                        version: [
                        {color: red },                      
                        {color: red },
                        {color: red },
                        {color: red },
                        {color: red },
                        {color: red },
                        {color: red },
                        {color: red },
                        {color: red }
                       ]
                    }
                ],
    }
  },
  methods: {

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add vue like this you don't return data.

```
data: {
  car: [ ... ]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0dgv1L4h/2/

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `item-text` and `item-value` props to specify the property name to use form `items`

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      cars: [{
          name: 'McQueen',
          versions: [
            { color: 'red' },
            { color: 'green' },
            { color: 'blue' }
          ]
      }, {
          name: 'Tesla',
          versions: [
            { color: 'orange' },
            { color: 'white' },
            { color: 'black' }
          ]
      }],
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container fluid>
      <div v-for="car in cars">
        <h4>{{car.name}}</h4>
        <v-select 
          label="Version"
          :items="car.versions" 
          item-text="color" 
          item-value="color">
        </v-select>
      </div>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if i just want to display index in select ?

Comment: for example instead red  give 0, green give 1, blue give 2

Comment: replace red with 0, green with 1 in versions array or add an other property like `{ color: 'red', index: 0 }` then use `item-text="index`

Comment: I can't add nothing on the data , it's an APi

Comment: Use: `item-text="index" item-value="color"`, assuming car.versions ~= `[{color: 'red'},{color: 'green'}, {color: 'blue'}]`

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the `v-select` in the template to:

```html
<v-select
  v-for="(c,index) in car"
  :items="c.version"
  :key="index"
  item-text="color"
>
</v-select>
```

Then in the `car` Array, there needs to be quotes around each instance of `red`, i.e. `{color: 'red'}`.

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {

  },
  data() {
    return {
     car: [
        {
          name: 'McQueen',
          version: [
            {color: 'red' },                      
            {color: 'red' },
            {color: 'red' },
            {color: 'red' },
            {color: 'red' },
            {color: 'red' },
            {color: 'red' },
            {color: 'red' },
            {color: 'red' }
          ]
        }
      ],
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.19/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.19/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="app">
<v-app >
<h1>Selection</h1>
<v-select
  v-for="(c,index) in car"
  :items="c.version"
  :key="index"
  item-text="color"
>
</v-select>
</v-app>
</div>
```